# Problem in setting DefaultSelectedItems for a dropdown/combobox in Power Apps

Tags: datatable, drop-down-menu, gallery, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a 'Leave Requests' dataverse table that have a column Approval Status. This is of type choice (Approved,Pending,Rejected).

To make editable table i made a gallery, passed the datasource of the table and inserted dropdown to select the approval status.
In DefaultSelectedItems option when I am passing the command ThisItem.'Approval Status' its giving me the following error

" This formula uses scope, which is not presently supported for evaluation "

Funny thing is when passing the same command in placeholder for the combobox/dropdown its showing me the actual value in the table without giving me any error.

Couldnt find any solution related to this

Comment: Try using `ThisItem.'Approval Status'.Value` once. Also, Make sure your column settings and combo box settings are same for allowing single selection or multiple selection. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: yeah tried that too but now showing error on Value keyword 
'Name isn't defined. Value isn't recognized'.. 

Checked the selection type too both in table field and the dropdown. both are same !